# How to replace / uninstall Email application from android emulator

Tags: android, email

Is there any way to uninstall/replace the inbuilt application in android emulator so that i can install my customized apps for Mail, Contacts, Music etc.

I have downloaded android 2.2 code for Email application and i want to modify certain things and install.

Please let me know if there is any way.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in replacing the apps in `/system` while the emulator is running, since the emulator doesn't save `/system` anyway.

In order to permanently replace apps in `/system`, one can edit the `system.img` file. It's quite easy really. As easy as extracting, moving files around, and compressing it back.

http://www.rodneybeede.com/Customize_an_Android_system_img.html

Answer (score 2):

I have done this way:

```
adb shell
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock1 /data
rm /system/app/MyAppName.apk
rm -rf /data/data/package_name_here/
mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system
mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock1 /data
pm uninstall package_name_here
exit
```

**Take care points**:

You have to provide details of your application:

**Line number 4:** rm /system/app/**MyAppName.apk**

**Line number 5:**  rm -rf /data/data/**package_name_here**/

**Line number 8:** pm uninstall **package_name_here**

**Done**

Comment: using command promt please go to upto android-sdk-windows -> platform-tools and then do above

Answer (score 1):

Launch your emulator, then make sure it is connected via adb, by typing:

```
adb -e devices
```

Make /system writable, by typing:

```
adb -e remount
```

Backup & remove Email.apk:

```
adb -e pull /system/app/Email.apk
adb -e rm /system/app/Email.apk
```

Push you own Email.apk:

```
adb -e push Email.apk /system/app
```

That's about it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. adb -e rm /system/app/Email.apk is not working, i tried rm from adb sheel but it says rm failed for Email.apk, Directory not empty.

Comment: Oh, I hate it when this happens. Did you remember to remount? Also, you can try launching the emulator from the command line, with the partition size parameter. Assuming, for example, that your emulator name is emu, you can do it like this: emulator @emu -partition size 128.

Answer (score -1):

All i can say is i am also trying to find the solution but you can try an alternative, try uninstalling unnecessary apps by system app remover and now installing a application similar for the same purpose from market and see if it works the same.